# Laminate flooring

Tags: floor, laminate-floor

Had to replace sub floors in mobile home. Installer said underlayment is not needed. New floors are moving up and down and creating problems. He also used 1/2 plywood and there was some past repairs done with 3/4 . He did not remove all the 3/4 and put the 1/2 next to it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's your question? If it's "is this OK", then we'll at least need some pictures, but either way it's probably too opinion-based for us.

Comment: So your installer did a poor job.  Call them back to make good, and if they don't, start a legal complaint.  Don't dally, they may have done the same poor work for others.

Answer (score 2):

1/2" is not suitable for floor use by itself, and putting 1/2" next to 3/4" (creating a 1/4" bump) is clearly not acceptable work. Unlikely that you'll manage to get the person who did that in the first place to do it correctly, but you can certainly give them bad word of mouth around town or electronically so others don't get burned.